# Join of Two Subgroups and Their Indices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, then $|K : H \cap K| \le |H \vee K : H |$, where $H \vee K =  \langle H \cup K \rangle$ denotes the join of  $H$ and $K$.

Here is a fact that I have available: If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, then $|K : H \cap K | \le |G : H|$. I realize this may seem trivial, but am I correct in thinking that the problem would follow easily from the aforementioned fact, since $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $H \vee K$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S = H \cap K$ and $U = H \lor K$.

We know:
$$|U:S| = |U:K||K:S|$$

Also, since $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $U$:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
|U:S| &\le& |U:H||U:K| \\
|U:K||K:S| &\le& |U:H||U:K| \\
|K:S| &\le& |U:H| \\
\end{array}$$
$\blacksquare$

Comment: So, am I right in assuming that my proof is incorrect? If so, where exactly did it go wrong?